# GeoJSON file has invalid coordinates

Tags: geojson

I'm looking at public data provided by my local government, and it appears the coordinates provided in the GeoJSON data don't correspond to real latitude / longitude values. Is there a format that's being used here that I can convert to real coordinates?

```
 "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "No":0,
            "Location":"Parnell Street",
            "No Spaces":"21 P&D (Total)",
            "Exact Location":"At Jury's",
            "Tariff":"�3.20",
            "Hours of Operation":"Mon-Sat 07.00-19.00, Sun 14.00-18.00",
            "Clr-Way":"FALSE",
            "X_Value":315763.7318,
            "Y_Value":234926.3662,
            "Zone":"Yellow"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               315763.7318,
               234926.366199999989476
            ]
         }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are in the Irish Grid Reference format:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_grid_reference_system

Comment: Do not post details as an answer, please edit your question and add aditional details there.